# Excel 2010: Move cells from vertical data to horizontal with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

**Excel 2010**

I want to move the following data from it's vertical state to horizontal data.  I would like a solution in VBA please.  (I already have a formula).

Order = (A10)    Result = (B10)  runs over 1000 rows

```
| Order1         | result                                                                       
| line1          | result 1
| line2          | result 1
| line3          | result 1
| line4          | result 1
| line5          | result 1
| line6          | result 1
| line7          | result 1
| line8          | result 1
|      br        |                                                                           
| Order2         | result                                                                   
| line1          | result 1
| line2          | result 1
| line3          | result 1
| line4          | result 1
| line5          | result 1
| line6          | result 1
| line7          | result 1
| line8          | result 1
```

I want it to resolve as:

```
Order 1  |  result1  |  result2  |  result3  |  result4  |  result5  |  result6  |  result7  |  result8  |  
Order 2  |  result1  |  result2  |  result3  |  result4  |  result5  |  result6  |  result7  |  result8  |
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**
My current formula is this:
(C10)  `=IF(A3="Order1 ",1,0)`  (result:  1)
(D10)  `=IF($C3=1,B3,0)`        (result:  result from line1)
(E10)  `=IF($C3=1,B10,0)`       (result:  result from line2)
and so on.

I then copy and autofill the entire sheet of data and it fills it all in.
And I build the new table this way.

When I macro record it doesn't record the actual formulas that I have in the cells.

Comment: Most of the transpose answers resolve both columns to single lines.  I need to take it from the pivot (ie Order1) then moving just the results to their new columns. As I pointed out, I do have a formula that does it, however I would like it in VBA.  I've been looking at this for days.

Comment: Excel can transpose the table using "copy" and "paste special…". These two commands should also be available in VBA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we start with:

[image]

with a blank between orders in *Sheet1*, then this macro:

```
Sub reorg()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet, N As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim v As Variant
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    N = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    j = 1
    k = 1

    For i = 1 To N
        v = s1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        If v = "" Then
            j = j + 1
            k = 1
        Else
            s2.Cells(j, k) = v
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

will produce this in *Sheet2*

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To use **A10** as both the start and destination, use:

```
Sub reorg()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet, N As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim v As Variant
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    N = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    j = 10
    k = 1

    For i = 10 To N
        v = s1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        If v = "" Then
            j = j + 1
            k = 1
        Else
            s2.Cells(j, k) = v
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm an idiot :)  (exhausted) I copied the wrong column data over - your code worked, but I needed to put in `v = s1.Cells(i, 2).Value` not `1`.  Your answer is perfect, thank you.  :)

Comment: Thank you.  I plan to pair this with a VBA snippet that moves columns around so I can slide it in to match other data already in the book.  This has saved me a lot of time, thank you.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain. Is there a way to start the process on A10 and paste it to A10 on the next sheet?  I've tried using A10 in `N = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` (& associated others) and I keep getting debugging errors.  My data starts on row 10 & it's picking all my headers :D